Causal variables and causal independence of the noise variables
In causality, my understanding is that, if we have causal variables $S_i$, we must have / assume that the (exogenous?) noise variables associated with each $S_i$ are causally independent of each other. My understanding is that this is analogous to the error independence assumption for statistical inference. But, outside of certain physics experiments — especially if we're dealing with any kind of system, which is nearly always the case (again, outside of the aforementioned physics experiments) — wouldn't there always be some kind/degree of causal entanglement between the noise variables? So how can we realistically ever perform causal inference? Then again, wouldn't this same reasoning hold for correlation between errors in statistical inference? And yet, we usually have little problem in performing statistical inference (even excluding bad (abuse of) statistics cases where the experimenters don't properly account for error independence)? I'm just trying to clarify my understanding/thoughts here. Is this just a case of, "yes, realistically, in nearly all real-world experiments (outside of the aforementioned physics experiments), the errors / noise variables are correlated / causally entangled, but it's a matter of degree, and so, the more we account for / minimize this correlation / causal entanglement, the more accurate our statistical/causal inference is, and so this is just a natural part of the philosophy of statistics/causality being about failing to falsify something, rather than "proving it as being true"."?
Also: If we're not sure if some variables have causally independent noise variables, is there some way to test/check for this? After all, we have methods in statistical inference to test/check for correlation between error terms, right?

Consider a system described by the behavior and interrelations of a finite set of variables $\mathcal{V}=\{V_i\}_{i=1}^m$, where each variable $V_i$ is a function/mechanism $f_i$ evaluation of some other variables, known as the causal parents $\operatorname{pa}(V_i)\subseteq\mathcal{V}\setminus\{V_i\}$, and some latent background noise $U_i$, such that $V_i=f_i(\operatorname{pa}(V_i),U_i)$ almost surely. The graph $\mathcal{G}$ encodes all direct causal relations $V_i\leftarrow V_j$ and $V_i\leftarrow U_j$, typically represented as a directed acyclic graph (DAG). This setup is known as the Structural Causal Model (SCM) framework, introduced by Prof. Judea Pearl.
It is a misconception that all $U_i$ must be mutually independent or uncorrelated to perform causal inference. The conditions for identification are dependent on the specific causal query and on $\mathcal{G}$. In other words, once a causal query is posed, the assumptions encoded in $\mathcal{G}$ determine whether causal inference for that particular query is feasible, even if some background noises are correlated.
For example, consider the causal query to be the post-intervention distribution of $Y\in\mathcal{V}$ after intervening on $X\in\mathcal{V}$ to set it to the value $x\in\operatorname{supp}X$. This is denoted by $p_Y(y\mid\operatorname{do}(X=x))$.

Experimental setting: When you can experimentally intervene, you effectively replace the mechanism $X=f_X(\operatorname{pa}(X),U_X)$ with $X=x$, eliminating the involvement of $U_X$. Hence, independence between $U_X$ and $U_Y$ is not required. Well-conducted experiments suffice to identify post-intervention distributions, assuming no selection bias occurs.
Observational setting: If experimental intervention is not possible, identification of $p_Y(y\mid\operatorname{do}(X=x))$ may still be feasible depending on $\mathcal{G}$. For instance, if there exists a set of variables $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq\mathcal{V}\setminus\{X,Y\}$ containing no descendants of $X$, such that $U_X\perp U_Y\mid \mathcal{Z}$, meaning $\mathcal{Z}$ blocks all backdoor paths from $X$ to $Y$ in $\mathcal{G}$ after removing all arrows emanating from $X$, then observational causal inference for that query is feasible via the Backdoor Criterion. The query would be identified with $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{Z}p_Y(y\mid\mathcal{Z},X=x)$. However, it is possible that no such set exists, even though identification could be possible, as this criterion is a sufficient but not necessary condition for identification. There is an ample variety of criteria for identifying this and various other queries.

In conclusion, requiring all background noises in a system to be independent is an overly stringent condition for the identification of most causal inference queries.
Regarding the last question about the possibility of testing the (causal) independence of variables in a system: it is generally not possible without structural assumptions. It may be feasible under causal sufficiency, which posits that all causally relevant variables are measured and that there are no latent relevant variables. This is a very strong assumption.
